# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating a walkthrough activity with a ViewPager and fragments, I have been able to successfully create the walkthrough, but the issue is, I can only swipe to the front, if I try to swipe back the app crashes, I tried replicating it on another test app which worked perfectly both front and back, although that one uses a TextView while this one uses an ImageView.

I need help figuring out why it crashes while swiping to back.

```
public class WalkThroughActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager mPager;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    CustomPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    MyPageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk_through);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pagesContainer);
        List < Fragment > fragments = new ArrayList < >();
        fragments.add(ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.walkthrough_card_1));
        fragments.add(ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.walkthrough_card_2));
        fragments.add(ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.walkthrough_card_3));

        mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIndicator = new MyPageIndicator(this, mLinearLayout, mPager, R.drawable.indicator_circle);
        mIndicator.setPageCount(fragments.size());
        mIndicator.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mIndicator.cleanup();
    }

    static class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        List < Fragment > mFrags = new ArrayList < >();

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List < Fragment > frags) {
            super(fm);
            mFrags = frags;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            int index = position % mFrags.size();
            return mFrags.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

    }
}
```

**ContentFragment**

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

    private int mParam1;

    public ContentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ContentFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indicator_fragment, container, false);;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mParam1);
        return view;
    }

    public int getmParam1() {
        return mParam1;
    }

}
```

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.simpumind.shoopa, PID: 8207
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setInitialSavedState(Fragment.java:576)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:114)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1216)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you share your ContentFragment.newInstance(...) function please ?

Comment: @Cochi i have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that offending lines of code are

```java
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        int index = position % mFrags.size();
        return mFrags.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but this code is very bad. It makes the `ViewPager` believe that you have much more fragments than you actually have AND reuse the same fragement several times. Assume that `mFrags.size()` is 2 and  the `ViewPager` asks for #0, #1 and #2 - you would return the fragment #0 twice and the `ViewPager`  might try to pass the same fragment through lifecycle twice. This re-usage of fragments is most probably the source of the exception you see.

By the way, what's wrong with straightforward?

```java
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFrags.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFrags.size();
    }
```

Comment: You are right, that was the culprit, i used the straightforward way, and it worked, Thanks.